# Flash messages not shown after redirect in MyFaces while it worked in Mojarra

Tags: jsf, message, myfaces, omnifaces, flash-scope

I've my own ExceptionHandlerWrapper to manage ViewExpiredException and other errors.

The idea is to catch the error, add some error message and redirect (with a redirection, not navigation) to the index page, where the error message will be displayed.

```
    fc.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
    Messages.addFlashError(null, "my message");
    Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
    flash.put("foo", "hello");
    fc.getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
```

However, flash messages are not stored (but foo is present in the flash scope).

This was working in mojarra, but I moved to myfaces 2.2.4 and it stopedd working. Any idea?
 (also using omnifaces 1.8.1)
Thanks.

Comment: Clearly a Myfaces bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at MyFaces source and it appears that they explicitly need an additional [`Flash#setRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#setRedirect(boolean)) call on top of [`Flash#setKeepMessages()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#setKeepMessages(boolean)). Although the Javadoc is admittedly not crystal clear on this, I'd expect that calling `setRedirect(true)` is only necessary for Flash attributes, not for Flash messages, which has its own `setKeepMessages(true)` call.

So, basically, you should be doing as follows:

```
fc.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
Messages.addFlashError(null, "my message");
Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
flash.put("foo", "hello");
fc.getExternalContext().getFlash().setRedirect(true); // <-- Add this.
fc.getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
```

However, as you're already using JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), which already implicitly calls `setKeepMessages(true)` when you use [`Messages#addFlashXxx()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/1.8/org/omnifaces/util/Messages.html#addFlash(java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage)) methods, and also implicitly calls `setRedirect(true)` when you use [`Faces#redirect()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/1.8/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#redirect(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) method, you could get away with just the following which does exactly the same as above "mess":

```
Messages.addFlashGlobalError("my message");
Faces.setFlashAttribute("foo", "hello");
Faces.redirect("index.xhtml");
```

No need for a custom phase listener.

Comment: What does `Flash#setRedirect()` actually do?

Comment: @Tiny: It's intented to let flash messages survive a double redirect, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it temporarily with a PhaseListener. I don't like it, but it works for now

What I do is, whenever I add a flash message, I also put it in flash scope:

```
     Messages.addFlash(null, new FacesMessage(severity, summary, detail));

    context.getExternalContext().getFlash().put("messages", context.getMessageList());
```

Then I restore them in a phaseListener

```
public void beforePhase(final PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();

    if (PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE.equals(event.getPhaseId())) {
        if (!facesContext.getResponseComplete()) {
            this.restoreMessages(facesContext);
        }
    }
}
private int restoreMessages(final FacesContext facesContext) {
    final Object flash = facesContext.getExternalContext().getFlash().get("messages");
    if (flash != null) {
        List<FacesMessage> messages = (List<FacesMessage>) flash;


        int restoredCount = messages.size();
        for (Object element : messages) {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, (FacesMessage) element);
        }
        return restoredCount;
    }
    return 0;
}
```